# How can I find newly found line in a continuous pipe?

Tags: command-line, pipe

Suppose you have a command `mycmd` that send a continous flow in a pipe.

You want to print only each newly occurences.

How would you do it?

The command

```
mycmd | sort -u
```

is not valid since I have to wait until mycmd has finished.

It is obviously possible to work with files but I am sure there may be a more direct way.

Comment: I don't really understand your pipe (what is `grep-ip(s)`?  `jwh-orgname`?) but you may find some helpful ideas here: [How to get only the unique results without having to sort data?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/how-to-get-only-the-unique-results-without-having-to-sort-data)

Answer (score 1):

`sort` would not show anything, because `sort` can't work on data streams coming on STDIN that has no EOF (End Of File).

`sort` will only work if the `mycmd` ends at some point, then `sort` will see the EOF, and work on the content.

---

To get unique content(s) on a data stream, you can use `awk` with an array to store the record counts:

```
mycmd | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

`seen[$0]` checks if the line is seen in the array `seen` by getting it's value. If the line is not present `seen[$0]` would return `0` (false), then the negation (`!`) test becomes true, and the line is printed (default action). `++` increments the value by 1, so next time the negation test would be false for any duplicate line.